# ListView - GridView - Header Tooltip

Tags: wpf, gridview, header, tooltip

I want to be able to have the tooltip of a column header the same with the Content.

As in, if my first column of a ListView with GridView contains the Names and the Header: "Name", then the tooltip of the header (that button you can press) should have the tooltip: "Name"

I have the following code for a ListView which has the GridView with some columns :

```
 <ListView x:Name="ListViewResidents" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Residents.View}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" >
                        <GridViewColumnHeader x:Name="GridViewHeaderName"  Content="Name" Command="{Binding SortCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=GridViewHeaderName}"  ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=GridViewHeaderName, Path=Content}"/>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"  >
                        <GridViewColumnHeader  x:Name="GridViewHeaderFirstName" Content="Firstname" Command="{Binding SortCommand}" Tag="FirstName" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=GridViewHeaderFirstName}"  ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=GridViewHeaderName, Path=Content}"/>
                </GridViewColumn>
                  <GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=BirthDate, StringFormat=d}"  >
                        <GridViewColumnHeader x:Name="GridViewHeaderBirthDate"  Content="Birth Date" Command="{Binding SortCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=GridViewHeaderBirthDate}" ToolTip="Some Text"  />
                </GridViewColumn>
```

The binding I created for the first column's header tooltip does not work, whereas the tooltip for the BirthDate column works. I know I can just set the tooltip to Name or Birth Date but I'm trying to find a way not to do that.

Any Ideas? 
Thank you!!!
Cosmin

--- EDIT --- I tried mark it as answered but I won't let me: my reputation is to low:
I found the solution. Eventually. I don't know why it took me so long to figure it out.

I had to change the binding to

> RelativeSource=Self

. So, it looks like this:

```
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" >
                        <GridViewColumnHeader ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self} , Path=Content}" Content="Name" Command="{Binding SortCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=GridViewHeaderName}"  />
                </GridViewColumn>
```

It works great now! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in your `Ressource`

```
<Window.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="nameTemplate">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  Margin="-6,0">
                    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Green" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </ToolTip>
                    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Window.Resources>
```

Invoke this template with `StaticResource`

```
"{StaticResource nameTemplate}"
```

Comment: Invoke it where exactly? In the Style it will be an error. Furthermore, if I have 10 columns, then I'll need to make 10 DataTemplates?